# Hypothesis testing involving two parameters in a 2-parameter exponential family

Tags: hypothesis-testing, exponential-family

> Let $(X, Y)$ be distributed according to the exponential family density $f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}(x,y)=c( \theta_1 , \theta_2 )h(x,y)exp( \theta_1x+ \theta_2y)$.
> Show that the only unbiased test for testing $H_{0} : \theta_{1} \leq a, \theta_{2} \leq b$ against $H_{1}:\theta_{1} > a$ or $\theta_{2} > b_1$ or both, is $\phi(x, y) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the level of the test.

I am unable to combine the given hypothesis into a single parametric hypothesis meaningfully, since, for instance, if I consider $H_0: \theta_1+\theta_2 \leq a+b$, it might be accepted but $H_1: \theta_1>a$ might still be true. Is it correct to test the hypotheses separately and see which region is common or something similar? Please help.

Edit:
[image: Was trying this]

In particular, I'm stuck at finding points in H1 such that the power becomes < alpha, contradicting unbiasedness for a non-constant test function.

Comment: You might find it helpful to plot all the relevant regions in the $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ plane.

Comment: @whuber The given $H_0$ corresponds to a south-west region, but how do I proceed?

Comment: I would begin with a definition (or some quantitative characterization) of an "unbiased test."

Comment: I've edited the post. @whuber

Comment: Thank you.  What does "$\phi$" refer to?

Comment: It's any test function that is not the constant $\alpha$. @whuber

Comment: I am having a hard time choosing which of many standard definitions of "test function" to apply to this question.  In particular, $\phi=\alpha$ implies you have a randomized test in mind -- so that basically the issue comes down to showing there does not exist any unbiased unrandomized test.  Please describe $\phi$ in your post.

Comment: I've taken it to be a test function that could be randomized or non randomized. Randomized tests such that $\phi$ = 1 in some region and $\gamma$ in some other region and 0 somewhere else could also be unbiased. @whuber

Comment: Is the test $\phi(x,y)=\alpha$ or $\phi(x,y)>\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

One point missed out a bit here (IMHO) is the joint density belonging to the exponential family. As $f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}(x,y)=c(\theta_1 ,\theta_2) h(x,y) \exp(\theta_1x+\theta_2y)$ and considering the curved exponential parametrization $L(X;c(\theta))=h(X)\exp\left(c(\theta)^TT(X)-A(c(\theta))\right)$ we get

$$h(X)=h(x,y),\quad c(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \theta_1 \\ \theta_2 \end{pmatrix},\quad T(X)=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix},\quad A(c(\theta))=-\log c( \theta_1 , \theta_2 )$$

keep the sufficient statistic $T(X)$ in mind, we'll get back there in a second.

---

Consider a univariate hypothesis testing problem for $f_\theta(X)$ that belongs to the exponential family, for example $H_0:\theta\le 0,\quad H_1:\theta>0$. The [Karlin–Rubin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem) tells us that the threshold test $$\varphi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x > x_0 \\
0 & \text{if } x < x_0
\end{cases}$$
with $x_0$ chosen so ${E}_{\theta_0}\varphi(X)=\alpha$ is UMP of size $\alpha$ for testing the composite hypotheses $H_0: \theta \leq \theta_0 \text{ vs. } H_1: \theta > \theta_0$. Moreover, if $c(\theta)$ is a strictly increasing function then $T(X)$ is the optimal test statistic for testing $H_0~\text{vs.}~H_1$ noted above. Optimal, in the sense that the $\alpha$-level test $\{T(X)\ge c_\alpha\}$ is UMP.

---

One of the major setbacks of the Karlin-Rubin theorem is that it is not generalizable for the multivariate case. However, given the form of $T(X)$, we can do a naughty trick here: We write the functions

$$L(x,c(\theta))=\sqrt{h(x,y)}\exp\left(\theta_1x-\frac{1}{2}\log c(\theta_1,\theta_2)\right) \\ L(y,c(\theta))=\sqrt{h(x,y)}\exp\left(\theta_2y-\frac{1}{2}\log c(\theta_1,\theta_2)\right)$$

so $f_{\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}}(x,y)=L(x,c(\theta))\cdot L(y,c(\theta))$. For each of the "marginal" distributions we can formulate the relevant univariate hypotheses (e.g. $H_0:\theta_1\le a,\quad H_1: \theta_1>a$) and construct a corresponding threshold test, $\varphi(x),\varphi(y)$ of level $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ ([Bonferroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction)) and eventually we can write the "double-threshold" test:

$$\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(x)\cdot\varphi(y)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x > x_0 \text{ AND } y>y_0 \\
0 &  otherwise
\end{cases}$$

As we used the Bonferroni correction, the test is UMP and is *at least* $\alpha$-level.